# Why does this Salt run fail with "Unable to determine Chocolatey version"?

Tags: cloud, salt-stack, chocolatey, orchestration

Trying Cloud Orchestration using Salt. Goal is to install packages on Windows using Chocolatey via Salt.

- Success: Chocolatey installed on windows.
- Failure: Successive packages not installed on Windows using salt's chocolatey module. They do when u do locally.

Two Windows 2012 instances on AWS on which I installed Chocolatey.

```
$ sudo salt 'windows\*' test.ping
windows2-minion: True
windows-minion: True
```

Both got installed with Chocoloatey 0.9.9.11 version. Next, I was trying to install packages on these machines/minions from master by firing command (OR Any other package name):

```
$ sudo salt 'windows*' chocolatey.install jdk7
```

But I got the error:

```
$ sudo salt 'windows*' chocolatey.install jdk7  
windows2-minion: ERROR: Unable to determine Chocolatey version  
windows-minion: ERROR: Unable to determine Chocolatey version
```

I am using Salt 2015.8.1 (Latest version). Master is on RHEL 7. All machines are on AWS.

Comment: That's a really good question. I wonder if it has more to do with salt than it does with choco.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue, I was able to fix it by editing the chocolatey.py module.

Change lane 105 in C:\salt\bin\Lib\site-packages\salt\modules\chocolatey.py to:

```
cmd = [_find_chocolatey(__context__, __salt__)]
```

Tokenfo supplied the answer here on salt's github: [https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/28307](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/chocolatey.py)

The bug has already been fixed as you can see here: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/chocolatey.py

Presumably, this will be fixed in future versions of the salt installer, but for now just edit the line.